# Can't log in MySQL with newly created user, but any username without password is accepted

Tags: mysql, authentication, mysql5.6

I installed MySQL 5.6 on Windows, imported a database (as root), and created a new user with a password to access this database.

Connexion with the username and password does not work (tested with Workbench).

However, if I connect without password, login is accepted, but I don't see the database. Actually, this works with *any* username.

How do I connect with the newly created user? And how do I prevent connections with any username and no password, which look like a security issue?

Comment: I'd be interested to know why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a user (apparently configured by default) set with host `localhost`, no password, and an empty username. Deleting this user solved the issue.